# Как установить Windows с флешки, если биос её не видит но система Ubuntu - видит?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10

Недавно установил убунту на ноутбук и почистил его от виндовс 10(установка была совершена с флешки). ПОзже на туже флешку установил iso образ виндовс с этого ноутбука(тоесть система ubuntu видит флешку), но когда захожу в биос - там только ubuntu и неизвестный мне efi программой(она там была всегда и точно не является флешкой).

Также при загрузке компьютера возникла проблема, что перед появлением логотипа ubuntu, компьютер висит на черном экране всегда примерно одно и тоже время(+-58 секунд), при этом после этого ожидания ubuntu загружается за секунд 5-6.

Comment: Rufus сделает всё за тебя

Answer (score 0):

Отформатируй флешку в fat или ntfs.

Распакуй установочный диск в корень флешки.

Сделай раздел активным и через ms-sys перезапиши загрузочный сектор. В случае ntfs ещё поправь раздел через тотже ms-sys.

http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/

Для загрузки через UEFI на FAT перезапись загрузочного сектора иногда не нужна - главное выбрать в биосе загрузку именно с UEFI.